# Snowflake SQL Query Left Join Issue

Tags: sql, left-join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, isnull, snowsql

For one of our code, left join is not behaving properly in **snowflake**. Require your help if you can find solution around the same.

We have a sample data setup like mentioned below with basicc table join.

```
CREATE TABLE patient_test(pid INT);
INSERT INTO patient_test (pid) VALUES (100);

CREATE TABLE pateint_entry_test (pid INT,DateAdded DATETIME);
INSERT INTO pateint_entry_test (pid, DateAdded) VALUES (100, '2020-07-13');
```

Now look below code where I am just giveing you sample sub query that we are using with other query set.  Where our motivation was to get date entry for each patient based on given start/end date.

```
WITh patient_cte  AS(
          SELECT * FROM patient_test
      )
      ,
      dates AS(
       SELECT  DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT_TIMEZONE('EST', 'UTC', CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-07-06') AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ)),
                            CONVERT_TIMEZONE('EST', 'UTC', CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-07-12') AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ))) AS Total_Days,
                            CONVERT_TIMEZONE('EST', 'UTC', CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-07-06') AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ)) AS Start_Date,
                            CONVERT_TIMEZONE('EST', 'UTC', CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-07-12') AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ)) AS end_date
      )
      ,
      cte2 (date) as (
      SELECT TO_DATE(START_DATE) FROM dates
      UNION ALL
      SELECT TO_DATE(DATEADD(day, 1, date)) FROM cte2 WHERE date < (SELECT TOP 1 END_DATE FROM dates)
      ),
      cte3 AS (
          select * from patient_cte
              cross join cte2
      )

      SELECT cte3.pid as p_pid,
        pateint_entry_test.pid as p_entry_pid,
        pateint_entry_test.DateAdded,
        cte3."DATE" ,
        IFNULL( pateint_entry_test.DateAdded, cte3."DATE") AS CALCULATEDDATEMEASURED
     FROM cte3
        LEFT JOIN pateint_entry_test ON
            cte3.pid = pateint_entry_test.pid AND
            cte3."DATE" = TO_DATE(pateint_entry_test.DateAdded)
```

Output of the query gives result as below.
[image]

**Where you can see `CALCULATEDDATEMEASURED` for Row number 2 to 7 are coming as `2020-07-06 00:00:00`. But as `DAETADDED` is coming for null then it should come proper date based on `DATE` column value  ( Based on this condition `IFNULL( pateint_entry_test.DateAdded, cte3."DATE")`)**

Expecting below output from the query
[image]

Not sure what is wrong, but its not behaving as expected. Aprreciate your help on this. Thank you.

Comment: This looks like a bug that you should report to Snowflake.  I am curious why you are using the non-standard `IFNULL()` rather than the standard `COALESCE()`.  I doubt that makes a difference to your results, however.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff for reverting back, tried `coalesce()` earlier but it was behaving same way.

Comment: Should this statement have an order by date?  `(SELECT TOP 1 END_DATE FROM dates)`  This is difficult to reproduce or help debug with example data for the tables that you are referencing in your example code.

Comment: Thanks @MikeWalton for reverting, its a working sample query i have added here for easy debugging. You can run the same codebase in snowflake environment as well. Tried to add order by like you suggested but its not helping.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a bug, but it's due to type coercion based on the way you wrote your query. Here's your query with the TO_DATE logic applied in the IFNULL statement the same as it is in the join (along with a COALESCE to show that it produces the same result as IFNULL):

```
WITh patient_cte  AS(
          SELECT * FROM patient_test
      )
      ,
      dates AS(
       SELECT  DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT_TIMEZONE('EST', 'UTC', CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-07-06') AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ)),
                            CONVERT_TIMEZONE('EST', 'UTC', CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-07-12') AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ))) AS Total_Days,
                            CONVERT_TIMEZONE('EST', 'UTC', CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-07-06') AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ)) AS Start_Date,
                            CONVERT_TIMEZONE('EST', 'UTC', CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-07-12') AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ)) AS end_date
      )
      ,
      cte2 (date) as (
      SELECT TO_DATE(START_DATE) FROM dates
      UNION ALL
      SELECT TO_DATE(DATEADD(day, 1, date)) FROM cte2 WHERE date < (SELECT TOP 1 END_DATE FROM dates)
      ),
      cte3 AS (
          select * from patient_cte 
              cross join cte2 
      )
      SELECT cte3.pid as p_pid,
        pateint_entry_test.pid as p_entry_pid,
        pateint_entry_test.DateAdded,
        cte3."DATE",
        IFNULL( pateint_entry_test.DateAdded, cte3."DATE") AS ORIGINAL_ERROR,
        IFNULL( to_date(pateint_entry_test.DateAdded), cte3."DATE") AS CALCULATEDDATEMEASURED,
        coalesce(to_date(pateint_entry_test.DateAdded), cte3."DATE") as from_coalesce
     FROM cte3 
        LEFT JOIN pateint_entry_test 
            ON cte3.pid = pateint_entry_test.pid 
            AND cte3."DATE" = to_date(pateint_entry_test.DateAdded);
```

Running this in Snowflake produces this:
[image]